# How do I create a capture template that will capture as level 1 after a heading?

Tags: org-mode

Lets say for example that I have this todos.org:

```
* README
* Emacs Wayland
* Another Headline
```

How do I capture after `README`, like this:

```
* README
* New Entry
* Emacs Wayland
* Another Headline
```

I have tried `file+regex` and `file+function` but both capture
as a child level 2.
I would like to capture as level 1.

```lisp
(add-to-list 'org-capture-templates
                 '("k"          ; key
                   "Test"      ; name
                   entry        ; type
                   ;;(file+regexp (lambda () (concat  org-directory "agenda/todos.org")) "README")
                   (file+function (lambda () (concat  org-directory "agenda/todos.org"))(lambda () (goto-char (point-min)) (re-search-forward "\\(README\\)" nil t 1)))
                   "* %?" :unnarrowed t :prepend nil :kill-buffer t))
```

Comment: Is the `README` headline empty or does it have contents (possibly a whole subtree)? If it has contents, hhe regex solutions would break that structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `entry` type creates a child of the target entry. You may want to use the `plain` type instead.

Comment: Thanks that worked, added `outline-next-heading` and it works like a charm. :D

Comment: The `entry` type with a `file` target creates top-level headlines.

Answer (score 1):

Based on Nick's answer with some modifications. You can also send integer arguments to `org-move-subtree-down` to move it further down.

```lisp
(defun my/org-move-subtree-down ()
"Helper function for org captures"
  (goto-char (point-min))
  (outline-next-heading)
  (org-move-subtree-down))
```

Uncomment `:before-finalize` to use the latest org version which provides this.

```lisp
(setq my/capture-top-level 
        '("a" "Top level"
              entry
              (file "~/Documents/org/agenda/todos.org")
              "* %^{titles}\n\n%?"
              :prepend t
              :unnarrowed t
              ;;:before-finalize my/org-move-subtree-down)
        ))
(add-to-list 'org-capture-templates my/capture-top-level)
```

Only use this if you're not using `:before-finalize`, more of a hack but it works. Match any file name in which you want to run
this (e.g., todos.org).

```lisp
(add-hook 'org-capture-before-finalize-hook
          (lambda ()
            (let ((buff (replace-regexp-in-string "CAPTURE-" "" (buffer-name))))
              (when (string-match-p "todos.org" buff) (my/org-move-subtree-down)))))
```

---

Here's a slightly more idiomatic function to add to `org-capture-before-finalize-hook` - this is meant for older Org mode where the `:before-finalize` template property is not available.

While `org-capture` is running, it accumulates information about the capture in a dynamic variable `org-capture-plist`. One of the properties on that list is `:target` which is a list like this: `(file "/home/rick/Documents/org/agenda/todos.org")` - just like the entry in the template except that the path is fully expanded. So that can be used to get the filename, without having to munge the buffer name of the capture buffer:

```el
(defun my/before-finalize-func ()
  (let ((fname (cadr (plist-get org-capture-plist :target))))
     (when (and fname (string= fname (expand-file-name "~/Documents/org/agenda/todos.org"))
        (my/org-move-subtree-down))))

(add-hook 'org-capture-before-finalize-hook #'my/before-finalize-func)
```

Untested and may be missing some error checking.

Comment: One other promising  avenue of investigation I think is to use `org-refile` instead of `org-move-subtree-down`. I was going to try to do that next, but I'm feeling a bit burnt out ATM, so I'll take a break before attempting that :-)

Comment: Yea that's a possibility. You know what's funny that after all this I can't use `:before-finalize` because I'm getting constant errors:`Warning (org-element-cache): org-element--cache: Org parser error in capture-org.el::8508. Resetting. The error was: (error "rx ‘**’ range error")`. If I want to use it I need to figure out in what commit they added `:before-finailize` then figure out how to configure straight to that `:commit` and hope for no errors. My org built-in is 9.5.5 the latest is 9.7-pre which gives me errors but gives me access to `:begin-finalize`.

Comment: I've led you on a merry chase, haven't I? Sorry about that. The cache has caused problems in the past, but @yantar92 (the chief maintainer IIUC, but he is not active on Emacs SE) has improved it substantially and with current upstream, there have been no reports of breakage AFAIK. I know that he is very interested in getting such bugs squashed so I'd encourage you to reach out with the problems you encounter on the [Org mode ML](https://orgmode.org/worg/org-mailing-list.html).

Comment: I'll have to do that. I think it may be that the package maintainers are not up to date with the latest org or something wrong in my config that broke with the org update. Who knows, eventually I need to figure that out if I want to update my org package and use the new keys in org-capture-templates.

Comment: I added a slightly more idiomatic function for the normal hook at the end. Feel free to revert/delete/modify as you see fit.

Comment: The commit where the hook properties were introduced is [7f3a6cf6e72fe9968c6ef32211c754b7fe0172b6](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs/org-mode.git/commit/?id=7f3a6cf6e72fe9968c6ef32211c754b7fe0172b6)

Comment: @NickD Your function looks better than mine. I bet you have a great config. Where can I check out your config? Github? I figured out what the problem was and fixed it, now I can use the latest org with no issues. With the org update from 9.5 to 9.7, you're not allowed to call an org function outside of org-mode. I modified a yasnippet condition function to only call in org-mode else return t to expand snippets.

Comment: 1. You don't want to look at my config - trust me :-)  2. "... With the org update from 9.5 to 9.7, you're not allowed to call an org function outside of org-mode." - that's not quite true: some Org mode functions assume that the buffer they operate on is in Org mode (or Org agenda mode for some agenda functions) but there is no blanket prohibition: it depends on the function.

Comment: It is `(org-in-src-block-p)`, if you try running outside of org-mode you may not get it or perhaps you would, but ya that was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that the `README` section has contents, not just a headline. I'm also assuming that you want the new entry to be the second top-level headline, following the `README` section.

Here's a capture template that does that:

```el
    (defun my/org-move-subtree-down ()
      (goto-char (point-min))
      (outline-next-heading)
      (org-move-subtree-down))

    (setq my/capture-top-level 
            '("z" "Top level"
                  entry
                  (file "/path/to/foo.org")
                  "* %?"
                  :prepend t
                  :before-finalize my/org-move-subtree-down))
    (add-to-list 'org-capture-templates my/capture-top-level)
```

The `entry` type with the `file` target creates top-level headlines, the `:prepend t` makes sure that the new entry goes to the top of the file and the `:before-finalize` makes sure that it is moved down past the next subtree at the same level.

Regex solutions are inadequate for dealing with a `README` section with contents: they would break the structure.

---

EDIT: As the OP points out in a comment,the template-specific `:after-finalize` hook was introduced in Org mode 9.6 and is not available in previous versions of Org mode. Something similar could be done in earlier versions by using the `org-capture-after-finalize-hook` but that is run after *every* capture, so the hook function would have to check which capture is running the hook and decide whether to do something or not. Although I haven't tried it, I think it's possible but it's certainly much more awkward than the template-specific hook.

---

EDIT:
I had `:after-finalize` earlier but as the OP points out in the comments below, that is wrong (and I have now fixed it): it has to be `:before-finalize` so that it happens in the capture buffer; `:after-finalize` does not happen in the file where the capture ends up as I erroneously thought, it happens in the (probably completely unrelated) buffer where `org-capture` was invoked. My bad.

Comment: Thanks Nick. The `after-finalize` don't work, I think that's a config problem on my end. Works fine with M-X. The problem with your suggestion is it would work for my purpose but if I had `README` or `WHATEVER` at line 500, i cant call `:after-finalize` several times. `file+olp` would be a better solution or `file+function` ?

Comment: `:after-finalize` should work with `emacs -q` (i.e. without any configuration on your part other than the template above). Once you get that working, you can replace `org-move-subtree-down` with a different function that does whatever you want. The point is that the place that a regexp finds is (probably) not a good place to put a subtree (it would break the structure). `file+olp` is meant for captures that go further down in the hierarchy and you need to specify the full "path": AFAIK, it does not accommodate top-level captures.

Comment: I understand what you mean. Thanks.

Comment: I figured out what the problem was. I had to update to the latest org version which has the key `after-finalize` but even then I get this error `Cannot move past superior level or buffer limit`.

Comment: Are you trying with `org-move-subtree-down` or your own function?

Comment: BTW, I didn't realize that `:after-finalize-hook` is so recent - thanks for pointing that out. I added some information about how to do it in earlier versions (at least in theory), but upgrading to 9.6 for it is probably the best option.

Comment: Updated with straight, was using built in, hopefully no more random errors from latest org. I tried your template that you provided on a new org file. All I did was change the key to `1` and file to `~/nick.org`.

Comment: OK - I think I see the error of my ways. Can you try the revised template? It uses  a slightly more complicated function for the `:after-finalize` hook that hopefully takes care of all the cases.

Comment: I still get that error `Cannot move past superior level or buffer limit` I'm not sure why. I even moved from my vanilla emacs to doom default config to make sure it wasn't a problem with my config. Tried it with `emacs -q` 9.5 version and it did not work, probably cause I would have to load the new org, in order to do that i would need to use straight.

Comment: Double-check the version of Org mode you are using (`M-x org-version`) and the value of `org-capture-templates` (`C-h v org-capture-templates` - in particular, make sure that the `:after-finalize` setting reflects the updated template). You might want to post before-and-after snapshots of the Org mode file (please add them to your question). OTOH, if you'd rather give up at this point, I'll completely understand :-)

Comment: I think the problem is in your `after-finalize` :). It should be `before-finalize`. The after tries to modify the current file hence the reason for `Cannot move past superior level or buffer limit`. Now, if you want to avoid the latest org which brings errors and warnings.. I have a snippet that uses `org-capture-before-finalize-hook`, where can I post this? In your solution or create a new answer?

Comment: Probably create a new answer, but are you sure you want to do that? It will affect *every* capture template unless your function is careful (see my EDIT above). I am not convinced that `:after-finalize` is wrong, buit I'll have to experiment some more.

Comment: `:before finalize` works for me as well: it is run before the `org-capture-before-finalize-hook` which is empty in my case. The description states: `The capture buffer is still current when this hook runs and it is
widened to the entire buffer` which is enough for the function to work. But `:after-finalize` works as well: the buffer is then the buffer of the file (rather than the [indirect capture buffer](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Indirect-Buffers.html)) and the modifications happen in the file buffer. In this case, it makes no difference which one you use.

Comment: I used `:before-finalize`, as I mentioned previously. So no need for my hacky `add-hook` but it's there if I need to downgrade org. I take care of that with `string-match-p`. Put inside `my/org-move-subtree-down` the function `(message "Inside %s" (buffer-name))`, it will show that `:after-finalize` is not in the captured file. What does it show on your end? I added an answer.

Comment: My bad: you are right - with `:after-finalize` I'm back in the (unrelated) buffer where I invoked `org-capture` - I didn't test carefully enough. My apologies for sending you around the world just to end up next door from where you started: my only consolation is that both of us might have learnt something.

Comment: No problem, we both learn. Everyone benefits, including the people that will read this years later. Thanks for your help.